# TableController equivalent of EdmModel

Tags: entity-framework, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

I'm new this subject and trying to understand the differences between `TableController`, `ApiController`, and `ODataController`, so I can decide which one to use.  I will be using OData and I think that all three of these controller base classes supply OData functionality.  I will also be using Entity Framework Code First, so my default choice it seems would be `TableController`.  But I'm considering that one of the alternatives may better fit my scenario.

Using `ODataController` starts with building an EdmModel.  Although I looked at the library source code, I'm not seeing where `TableController` (together with `EntityDomainManager`) is building a static model like that.  Perhaps it doesn't "build" a model but simply wraps that of the `DbContext` by performing operations on the entity's `DbSet`?

But what about an OData query that involves a navigation property?  Does `TableController`/`EntityDomainManager` allow you to chain together a property path such as `Order.Customer.Name` in the query URL?  Is the routing done using a predefined model or on the fly?

Comment: I just  came across [this](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/140) which may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ApiController` is a WebAPI - no special functionality - just straight GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/etc. functionality that runs your code.

An `ODataController` is an `ApiController` that implements the OData specification for data access.

An Azure Mobile Apps `TableController` is an `ApiController` that implements the OData v3 specification with some extra bits to provide offline sync capabilities to a compatible client (specifically, the `MobileServiceClient` across iOS, Android, .NET (Xamarin/UWP/WP8.1) and Cordova)  This takes the complexity out of defining the OData endpoint.

There are semantic differences on how you define the endpoints, how to represent the query, etc.

In terms of how it builds the model - it just wraps the DbContext - your Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) must inherit from EntityData - this gives the model the additional columns necessary to do offline sync (and note the `Id` column must be a string).  Because a `TableController` is primarily a mobile capability, there are a bunch of caveats with their usage - relationships are particularly hard in an offline world, for instance.  `ODataController` (which is online only) supports relationships - `TableController` requires work to support them.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info.  I've been researching in the meantime.  (1) Seems that `ApiController` in fact [can have OData functionality](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options).  But I think you're saying it's best not to use it that way, right? (2) `ODataController` is for both "data access" *and modification*, right? (3) In saying that `ODataController` "is online only", you just mean offline sync isn't provided out-of-the-box, right? I think I could still code that myself.

Comment: @HappyNomad You really should use a TableController if you want to use offline sync. The Mobile Apps client SDKs expects a particular protocol and uses a particular JSON formatter in order to work. There are some differences in the way the ODataController sets up the endpoints, for instance. 

Also, the relationship functionality exposed by the ODataController is not leveraged by the Mobile Apps client SDK, so there is no benefit in using an ODataController. Why not just use a TableController?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I'd use a client [library](http://www.odata.org/libraries/) other than the SDK to benefit from `ODataController`.  I won't use `TableController` since its relationships support is poor and its offline sync doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: @HappyNomad in that case, there's not a lot of benefit in using the Mobile App server SDK, you should just host in an Azure Web App.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I thought both are now combined into "Azure App Service"?

Comment: @HappyNomad Yes indeed and there is a separate concept of the Mobile Apps client and server SDKs. You probably won't be a lot of benefit from these SDKs since you want to use the OData controller as you said. There's no difference between a web app and mobile app, aside from the Quickstart blade.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft Yes but can my Windows app still use [Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/) in that case?  I thought it's part of the same mobile client SDK.

Comment: @HappyNomad Ah yes, good point. I thought I had seen another comment where you said you wanted to do your own authentication, but if you're doing the built-in auth, then yes, you should use the mobile app client SDK. You don't need the server SDK though, unless you need to customize with your own auth provider.